# React Native - Navigate from screen with status bar to full screen

Tags: android, react-native, user-interface, navigation, fullscreen

I have 2 screens in my app, one with status bar and one without status bar. 1st screen is full screen(without status bar) which contains button to navigate to 2nd screen which is with status bar.

1st screen code to hide status bar:

render(){
  return (
    
  );
}

When I jump to 2nd screen from 1st and press back button on 2nd screen, 1st screen flickers(UI gets rearranged from status bar to full screen) layout as it hides status bar which is not hidden in 2nd screen. So ultimately, for a fraction of time, UI looks cracky.

I have tried to hide status bar on back press of 2nd screen but then it flickers UI of 2nd screen. Is there any work around to resolve this issue?

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I guess Add this code where you have StatusBar and UI flickering(UI gets rearranged from status bar to full screen).
Something Like This:

```
<StatusBar 
  barStyle={'dark-content'}
  translucent
  backgroundColor={'transparent'}
  hidden={false}
  />
 <View
 style={{
 ...styles,
 marginTop: StatusBar.currentHeight,
 }}
 >
 </View>
```

Basically when you give marginTop:StatusBar.currentHeight, to very next **View** of **StatusBar**, then you reserved StatusBar Place Before UI Rendering that’s why UI always render after statusBar and never happening re-arrangement OR flickering Of **UI**.
Get More Info and usage of StatusBar from React Native official documentation https://reactnative.dev/docs/statusbar

Answer (score 0):

I guess the code you're using to hide the bar is not the best way to go about it.
Have you tried something like this:
[React Native StatusBar](https://www.javatpoint.com/react-native-statusbar)

where you get to use what React Native gives you to handle this issue?
Even more because you need to be careful of what you use if you intend to build for both Android and iOS that end up having different behaviours.

I cannot comment on your question yet because of my reputation, but could you provide more details about your code structure please?